# Wrong column type - Found varchar2, Expected NVARCHAR2(255)

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i have a mapping configuration for a composite-key using fluent nhibernate and i need some help, because it is not working.

I have one class called Agencia that have a composite key for two Int16 collumns that are mapped as number on a oracle 11g database.

```
[Serializable]
public class AgenciaPK
{
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public virtual System.Int16 CdAgencia { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Int16 CdOrgaoArrecad { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        hashCode = hashCode ^ CdAgencia.GetHashCode() ^ CdOrgaoArrecad.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var toCompare = obj as Agencia;
        if (toCompare == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.GetHashCode() != toCompare.GetHashCode());
    } 
}

public class Agencia : AgenciaPK
{        
    public virtual OrgaoArrecad OrgaoArrecad { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public virtual string NmAgencia { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Digito")]
    public virtual string NrDigitoAgencia { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Número")]
    public virtual string NrAgencia { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public virtual string DsCompl { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Logradouro")]
    public virtual string NmLograd { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Bairro")]
    public virtual string NmBairro { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Nullable<short> IdSituacAgencia { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Cep")]
    public virtual System.Nullable<short> NrCep { get; set; }
}
```

I have another class called Convenio that have a composite key composed by one string collumn (CdConvenio) and another is int CdOrgaoArrecad.

```
 [Serializable]
public class ConvenioPK
{
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public virtual string CdConvenio { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cód. Órgão arrecadador")]
    public virtual System.Int16 CdOrgaoArrecad { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 13;
        if (CdConvenio != null)
        hashCode = hashCode ^ CdConvenio.GetHashCode() ^ CdOrgaoArrecad.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var toCompare = obj as Convenio;
        if (toCompare == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (this.GetHashCode() != toCompare.GetHashCode());
    } 
}

public class Convenio : ConvenioPK
{
    [DisplayName("Órgão arrecadador")]
    public virtual OrgaoArrecad OrgaoArrecad { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data início")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual System.DateTime DtInicioConvenio { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Data término")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual System.DateTime DtFinalConvenio { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Tipo")]
    public virtual short TpConvenio { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Tarifa")]
    public virtual short TpTarifaConvenio { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Valor tarifa")]
    public virtual Double VlTarifaConvenio { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Quantidade dias")]
    public virtual short QtDiasFloat { get; set; }
}
```

And when i access this class Agencia using this mapping class AgenciaMap, it works fine.

```
public class AgenciaMap : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<Agencia>
{        
    public AgenciaMap() {
        Table("SCI_AGENCIA");
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.CdAgencia, "CD_AGENCIA")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.CdOrgaoArrecad, "CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD");
        Map(x => x.CdOrgaoArrecad).Column("CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.NmAgencia).Column("NM_AGENCIA").CustomType("AnsiString").Length(30).Not.Nullable();

        References<OrgaoArrecad>(x => x.OrgaoArrecad, "CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD").ForeignKey().Not.Update()
          .Not.Insert()
          .Cascade.None().Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

But, when i try to access the class Convenio, using the class ConvenioMap:

```
 public class ConvenioMap : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<Convenio>
{        
    public ConvenioMap() {
        Table("CONVENIO");
        CompositeId()
           .KeyProperty(x => x.CdConvenio, "CD_CONVENIO")
           .KeyProperty(x => x.CdOrgaoArrecad, "CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD");

        Map(x => x.CdConvenio).Column("CD_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("varchar2(20)").CustomType("AnsiString").Length(20).Not.Nullable();            
        Map(x => x.CdOrgaoArrecad).Column("CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DtInicioConvenio).Column("DT_INICIO_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("DATE").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.DtFinalConvenio).Column("DT_FINAL_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("DATE").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TpConvenio).Column("TP_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("NUMBER(2,0)").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TpTarifaConvenio).Column("TP_TARIFA_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("NUMBER(2,0)").Not.Nullable();            
        Map(x => x.VlTarifaConvenio).Column("VL_TARIFA_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("NUMBER(15,2)").Not.Nullable();  
        Map(x => x.QtDiasFloat).Column("QT_DIAS_FLOAT").CustomSqlType("NUMBER(3,0)").Not.Nullable();

        References(x => x.OrgaoArrecad)
            .Column("CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD")
            .ForeignKey().Not.Update()
            .Not.Insert()
            .Cascade.None()
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

When i map a collumn that is the type string "CD_CONVENIO", i'm getting this error:

> Wrong column type in SCI.CONVENIO for column CD_CONVENIO. Found: varchar2, Expected NVARCHAR2(255)

The specific part of my code that i'm in doubt is this:

```
CompositeId()
           .KeyProperty(x => x.CdConvenio, "CD_CONVENIO")
           .KeyProperty(x => x.CdOrgaoArrecad, "CD_ORGAO_ARRECAD");
```

So, here is my question: What am i doing wrong?

Comment: sorry if stupid comment, but what is .CustomSqlType("varchar2(20)") exactly ?

Comment: Acording to FluentNhibernate API that i am using, it is the specific SQL type of database collum.

Comment: Sorry  It was really a stupid comment. I did not even notice the numerous oracle references and tag ;-) Did you give a try to :
Map(x => x.CdConvenio).Column("CD_CONVENIO").CustomSqlType("varchar2 (20)").Not.Nullable();